# AngularJS, select onChange or ngChange

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new using `angularjs` and the angular user interface. I'm interested in the  tag.

This is my `html`:

```
<select id="part1" ui-select2 ng-model="params.id" style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="">Provinsi</option>
    <option ng-repeat="v in prov" value="{{v.id}}" title="{{v.text}}"
    ng-selected="v.id == params.id">{{v.text}}</option>
</select>
<select id="part2" ui-select2 ng-model="params2.id" style="width: 200px;" ng-disabled="true">
    <option value="">Kabupaten</option>
    <option ng-repeat="y in kab" value="{{y.id}}" title="{{y.text}}"
    ng-selected="y.id == params.id">{{y.text}}</option>
</select>
```

and this my `app.js` :

```js
$http.get('json/provinsiData.json').success(function(datax) {
    $scope.prov = datax;
});

//part2 data
$http.get('json/acehData.json').success(function(datay) {
    $scope.kab = datay;
});

$scope.params = {}
$scope.params2 = {}
```

As you can see `select part2` is disabled.

How can I create an event change that works like the condition below?

```
if selected option of part1 is index 0
then select part2 disabled = false and load json part2 data.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Angular, we usually aren't looking for events to trigger changes. Instead, when the model changes, the view should update to reflect those changes.

In this case, the second element should be enabled (not disabled) depending on a value in the model. When the model value connected to the first select menu satisfies some condition, enable the second menu. Yes, technically there's an event, but we don't need to care about it, all that matters are the model's values.

Here's a simplified example of how this might work:

```
<select ng-model="selection.item">
  <option value="">Clothing</option>
  <option ng-repeat="item in clothes">{{ item }}</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="selection.size" ng-disabled="!selection.item">
  <option value="">Size</option>
  <option ng-repeat="size in sizes">{{ size }}</option>
</select>
```

The second select menu's `ng-disabled` attribute is a simple expression which basically evaluates to *"disable me if `selection.item` does not have a value"*. That could just as easily be a more complex expression or a function.

Here's [a plunkr based on the code above](http://plnkr.co/edit/6I6xCX?p=preview)

Comment: Ok, and if I still need to execute a function on select? Then what?

Comment: @sorin7486 how about a $watch on the variable the select updates?

Comment: yes, that would work but I wanted to use this for validation so I was trying to keep things in the template

Answer (score 8):

The angular-js select supports the ng-change attribute which may call any javascript method defined in scope. 
Example:

However your best bet may be just to evaluate an $scope expression in your ng-disabled= attribute, e.g. ng-disabled="params.id == 'X'".